# Implement MultiMap with Generics don't quite work in my Code and I cannot figure out why

Tags: java, generics, exception, methods, hashmap

I am still new to Generics and Hashmaps so go easy on me.
First the Code, which is just the Start what I need to do in this Class but I don't really understand what the Problem is

[image]

1 . What I need to do here is to implement the MultiMap Interface into the StringMapIO so that it takes just Strings in it ( did I do that right? ).

2. Then it have to write the key, Value inside of a given Bufferedwriter. Isn't it usually that you need a file or something else and create a Bufferedwriter that writes on it rather than put a Bw in as a parameter? (cause that's in the given Interface)
3. The Value of the given Hashmap is a `List<V>` which contains Strings (I implemented a class MultiHashMap for that which works fine and also implements MultiMap ) but here I try to make a new List which contains all the Values and then write it down with a loop. But I can't get the Values with getValues as you can see here, why is that? shouldn't it just work fine when I put in the MultiHashMap since it also implements MultiMap?

Edit: it says I should change the map.getvalue parameter as a String in the Interface but that is not the point of generics, so I am curious

Hopefully I described my Problem clear enough, if not ask right away.

Sorry I didn't know you need to copy and paste it, I will now post the class which are needed for this code

```
public class StringMapIO<K extends String, V extends String> implements MultiMapIO<K,V> { // TODO: change hierarchy and implement






     public void write(BufferedWriter writer, MultiMap<K, V> map) throws IOException {
    
     try { 
        
        for (String currentKey : map.getKeys()) {
            List<V> currentList = map.getValues(currentKey);
            for(String currentListValue : currentList) {
                
            }
        }
        
        
        
    } catch (KeyNotFoundException e) {
        throw new IOException("asd",e);
    }
    
}


@Override
public MultiMap<K, V> read(BufferedReader reader) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

```
public class MultiHashMap<K,V> implements MultiMap<K,V> {

HashMap<K, List<V>> myHashMap = new HashMap<>();




@Override
public Set<K> getKeys() {
    return myHashMap.keySet();
    }

@Override
public boolean containsKey(K key) throws NullPointerException {
    try {
        if(key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Key is not allowed to be null!");
        }
        if(myHashMap.containsKey(key)) {
        return true;
        }else {
        return false;
            }
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    return false;
    }

@Override
public List<V> removeKey(K key) throws KeyNotFoundException, NullPointerException {
    try {
        if(key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Key is not allowed to be null!");
        }
        if(myHashMap.containsKey(key)==false) {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException(); 
        }
        
        return myHashMap.remove(key);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    return null;
}




@Override
public List<V> getValues(K key) throws KeyNotFoundException, NullPointerException {
    try {
        if(key == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Key is not allowed to be null!");
        }
        if(myHashMap.containsKey(key)==false) {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException("Key is not in the Map");
        }
    
        return myHashMap.get(key);
        
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean removeValue(K key, V value) throws KeyNotFoundException, NullPointerException {
    try {
        if (key == null || value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Since the MultiHashmap allows no nullpointers, you have to put in key and value as parameter");
        }
        if(myHashMap.containsKey(key) == false) {
            throw new KeyNotFoundException();
        }
        List<V> list = myHashMap.get(key);
        list.remove(value);
        myHashMap.put(key, list);
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    
    return false;

}

@Override
public void addValue(K key, V value) throws NullPointerException {
    try {
        if (key == null || value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        List<V> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (myHashMap.containsKey(key) == false) {
            list.add(value);
            myHashMap.put(key, list);
            return;
        } else {
            list = myHashMap.get(key);
            list.add(value);
            myHashMap.put(key, list);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (key == null) {
            System.out.println("Key is not allowed to be null!");
        }
        if (value == null) {
            System.out.println("Value is not allowed to be null!");
        }
    }

}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return myHashMap.toString();
}

    


}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of image, so that people can read, copy and debug it. 
Also, it would be hard to answer without seeing the code of your `MultiMap` interface.

Comment: If you need only strings, why do you have `K extends String` instead of `String`?  Also class `String` can not be extended, because it's final.

Comment: Smth like this: `public StringMapIO implements MultiMapIO<String,String> { }`